# Backbone.js routes are not being triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, routes

I have a Rails 3.2.3 app with Backbone.js and I'm using pushState on my Backbone.history.

**The Problem**

When I click on a link which goes to say '/foo' to show appointment with ID: 1, then Backbone router gets to that first, which I can quickly see before Rails router takes over and complains that there is no route for /foo.

**My Backbone.js code**

Here is my backbone router.

```
window.AppointmentApp = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "foo": "foo",
        "appointments": "index",
        "appointments/:id": "show"
    },
    foo: function(){
        $("#app").append("foo<br />");
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.appointments = new Appointments();
        this.appointmentListView = new AppointmentListView({ collection: this.appointments });
        this.appointmentListView.render();
    },
    start: function() {
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    },
    index: function() {
        $("#app").html(this.appointmentListView.el);
        this.appointments.fetch();
    },
    show: function(id) {
        console.log("Enter show");
    }   
}));
```

It should stay on the same page and attach a 'foo' to the end of the #app div, but it never does.

**Backbone index viewer**

```
window.AppointmentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST["appointments/index"],
    events: {
        "click .foo": function(){Backbone.history.navigate("foo");},
    },
    comparator: function(appointment){
        return appointment.get('topic');
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        this.addAll();
        return this;
    },
    addAll: function() {
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(appointment){
        var appointmentView = new AppointmentView({model: appointment});
        this.$el.append(appointmentView.render().el);
    }
});
```

**app/assets/templates/appointments/Index.jst.ejs**

```
<h1>Appointments</h1>
<a href="/foo" class="foo">Say Foo</a>
<a href=appointments/add>Add</a>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I was using pushState as it allows me to keep a history and the Back button functionality.

The Backbone.history.navigate doesn't call my Backbone route, it calls the Rails route instead. How do I go about fixing this?

Should I be trying to setup Backbone to accept routes such as 'appointments/1' and taking control or do I have to use a click event with a Backbone.history.navigate call like above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return false from your `click .foo` event handler, otherwise the browser will continue as if you'd clicked the link normally and request the actual `/foo` page from the server.

I think you've also got the call to `Backbone.history.navigate("foo");` wrong - `Backbone.history` doesn't have a `navigate` function as far as I can see from the documentation.  You should actually be calling .navigate on your `Backbone.Router` instance, and passing in the `trigger` option to cause it to call trigger the route.  For example:

```
window.AppointmentApp.navigate("foo", { trigger : true } );
```

You may already know this but if you're planning on using pushState then you should really update your server side to support all the URLs that your client side does.  Otherwise if a user decides to copy & paste the URL into another tab, they will just run into rails complaining that there is no route.

Comment: I thought the whole idea behind pushState was that you didn't have to use URL fragments?

Comment: If I remove pushState and change your navigate line to "#/foo" then it all works, but with URL fragments not real URLs. I'm looking for a way to do this with pushState

Comment: @map7 Ah, sorry, I didn't quite see what you were asking.  I've updated my answer

Comment: The return false works, however I've had to stick with calling Backbone.history.navigate as this works and calling navigate on my router has caused other problems.